# does a zeta zero ever occur when $Re(\zeta(s))$ is at a minimum?

Tags: riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

The Lehmers' zeros for $\zeta(\frac{1}{2} + it)$ are quite close to each other in the value of the ordinate $t$. I am aware of the constraint on the Hardy Z function for which a local positive minimum or a local negative maximum would disprove RH.

My question is does a zeta zero ever occur when either $Re(\zeta(\frac{1}{2} + it))$ plotted vs. $t$ is at a minimum or when the $Im(\zeta(\frac{1}{2} + it))$ plotted vs. $t$ is at a maximum?

Thanks

Comment: The real part at a minimum? Minimum of what?

Comment: Minimum of the function $Re(\zeta(1/2 + it))$ plotted versus t.

Comment: would appreciate a comment if you took the trouble of voting down. Could you explain why you voted down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that if $\zeta(\frac{1}{2} + it)=u(t)+iv(t)$ and with $e^{i\theta(t)}\zeta(\frac{1}{2} + it)=Z(t)$ one has that $Z=u\cos \theta-v\sin \theta$ while $u\sin \theta+v \cos\theta=0$ so one gets $-v\sin \theta=u \sin^2\theta/\cos \theta=u/\cos \theta-u\cos \theta$ so $Z=u/\cos \theta$

But now if $Z(w)=0$ hence $u(w)=v(w)=0$ and $w$ is a minimum for $u$ so $u'(w)=0$ it follows that $Z'(w)=0$ and that is considered highly unlikely

Comment: Thank you. Does having such a zero (as described in the question) disprove RH?

Comment: why should it disprove it? it is definitely possible to have double zeroes on the critical line (this of course is deemed unlikely as noted but as of now has no bearing on RH); then since $u(t)=Z(t)\cos \theta (t)$ one gets that if $Z(w)=Z'(w)=0$ we have $u''(w)=Z''(w)\cos \theta(w)$ and there is no reason for $u''(w)$ not to be allowed to be positive so $w$ is a local minimum for $u$; the result quoted above that RH implies the decreasing monotonicity of $Z'/Z$ applies only in between zeroes of $Z$